# Symfony Security: How to use company ID and username as composite keys for user identification?

Tags: authentication, security, symfony6

symfony 6.3 security.
The user identifier should be a composite key, company id + user name:
when log in, the user at first has to specify the company, and it has to be checked if exists and is enabled; after that, the user has to enter the useridentifier (username or email), to be checked adding the company id to the database key, so that we can have same user identifiers for different companies. The admin feature as well has to work in the same way, managing users by company.